# How to create new json when adapter updates items from list in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, local-storage, android-recyclerview

I have a todo list with prepopulated items from a local json file. Initially, all the items are set to unchecked. However, when the user clicks an item it gets changed to checked/true and it is displayed back to the UI with this update. And this is all working now (I'm using gson to turn the json into Java pojo) but I need to persist this state, so that next time the user opens the application they can retrieve the items that were marked as checked still maintaining these changes. My idea is to create a new json file with the whole list but having these changes overwriting the initial values so that this would be file used instead of the initial one by stringfying it and saving it to a DB later on. But not sure how to do that from when an item is changed on the onClickListener on the adapter please?

```
class RecyclerItem(private val todoItem: TodoItem) : Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {

override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.apply {

        with(viewHolder.itemView) {
            tvTitle.text = todoItem.title
            rbIsCheckedStatus.isChecked = todoItem.isChecked

            rbIsCheckedStatus.setOnClickListener {
                todoItem.isChecked = !todoItem.isChecked
                rbIsCheckedStatus.isChecked = todoItem.isChecked
            }
        }

    }
}

override fun getLayout() = R.layout.recyclerview_item_row
}
```

And this is a sample for my json:

```
[
  {
  "title": "Item 1",
  "isChecked": false
  },
  {
  "title": "Item 2",
  "isChecked": false
  },
  {
  "title": "Item 3",
  "isChecked": false
  }
]
```

And model:

```
data class TodoItem (val title: String, var isChecked: Boolean = false)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You have to rewrite the json file with update value. But I strongly suggest db for handling data and changes

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. How would I do that though, do you know? I mean, on the adapter I only have access to one item not the whole list, so a bit confused because of that. And yes, my idea is to get this new json and save this string to a DB after.

Comment: yes, You can store data as many tables with relationship and write daos for retrive them

Comment: can you add your json file?

Comment: Sure, I've added the sample for the json now.

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room. And store all items with auto increment id(primary key) on first launch of app. Then get data from db for display in list  and update on db and local object when check and uncheck the item So you can keep state always

Comment: Okay, thank you. Will have a look.